# How to use Android Gradle without multi-project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I would like to create an android build with a single `build.gradle` file. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two `build.gradle`s, a project-level one and a module-level one. They are not the same. You can omit neither of them.

Comment: Well I think that requires a more proper explanation of **why** it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

It actually **is** possible.

The whole problem when trying to create an Android build with a single `build.gradle` comes from the fact, that a `plugins` block of the top-level `build.gradle` can only use plugins from Gradle plugin portal and cannot address anything from buildscript's classpath.

However, there is a `pluginManagement` block you can add to `settings.gradle`, that can be used to modify how plugins are resolved.

A working example:

```
// settings.gradle.kts

rootProject.name = "android_app"

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.name.startsWith("com.android")) {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    id ("com.android.application") version "4.2.2"
}

group = "pl.gieted.android_app"
version = "1.12-SNAPSHOT"

android {
    compileSdkVersion(31)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = group.toString()
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(31)
        versionName = version.toString()
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```